# Make a div with buttons inline

Tags: html, css

How do you make a Div with 2 buttons become inline?

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="break-label"> Break Length </h2>
  <div id="button">
    <button id="break-decrement">
                    handleClickBreakDecrement
                </button>
    <p id="break-length"> 5 minutes or something </p>
    <button id="break-increment">          
                    handleClickBreakIncrement
          </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The div with the ID="button" must be inline  like this:

```
   **handleClickBreakDecrement** 5 minutes or something **handleClickBreakIncrement**
```

Instead of this:

```
  **handleClickBreakDecrement** 
5 minutes or something 
**handleClickBreakIncrement**
```

I tried using display : inline but nothing happened

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The paragraph element (`<p>...</p>`) between your two buttons is a *block-level* element, which accounts for the behavior you're witnessing.

To fix, either set `display: inline` on the paragraph element, or replace it with an inline element like `<span>...</span>`:

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="break-label"> Break Length </h2>
  <div id="button">
    <button id="break-decrement">handleClickBreakDecrement</button>
    <span id="break-length"> 5 minutes or something </span>
    <button id="break-increment">handleClickBreakIncrement</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay Thank you, I thought that as long that the paragraph element is enclosed within the div, it will become display:inline. Great solution and thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 2):

To make the inner buttons and paragraph render on the same line, you can set their CSS property `display` as `inline-block`, like the following snippet:

```css
#button > button, p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2 id="break-label"> Break Length </h2>
    <div id="button">
      <button id="break-decrement">
                handleClickBreakDecrement
            </button>
            <p id="break-length"> 5 minutes or something </p>
      <button id="break-increment">          
                handleClickBreakIncrement
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Three feasible ways to achieve:

```css
#button {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="break-label"> Break Length </h2>
  <div id="button">
    <button id="break-decrement">
      handleClickBreakDecrement
    </button>
    <p id="break-length"> 5 minutes or something </p>
    <button id="break-increment">          
      handleClickBreakIncrement
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#button button,
#button p {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="break-label"> Break Length </h2>
  <div id="button">
    <button id="break-decrement">
      handleClickBreakDecrement
    </button>
    <p id="break-length"> 5 minutes or something </p>
    <button id="break-increment">          
      handleClickBreakIncrement
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#button {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#button button,
#button p {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="break-label"> Break Length </h2>
  <div id="button">
    <button id="break-decrement">
      handleClickBreakDecrement
    </button>
    <p id="break-length"> 5 minutes or something </p>
    <button id="break-increment">          
      handleClickBreakIncrement
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, Never thought that display:flex also can do the work. I learned something new . Thank you